# Ordering of results based upon dependencies

Tags: clojure

I'm looking at resolving compilation targets.. Say if I have a set of compilation targets, each with a set of its own dependencies.

```
A -> B C

B -> C E 

C -> E F

D -> NONE

E -> F

F -> NONE
```

The targets cannot be added to a pass unless its dependencies are are in a previous pass. i.e: I want to have a list of compilation steps looking like this:

```
[[D F] [E] [C] [B] [A]]
```

So, D and F are compiled, then E, then C, etc... How can this be done?

Comment: [`topological sorting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A map would be a natural way to represent your direct dependencies

```
(def direct-dependencies 
  {:a #{:b :c}, :b #{:c :e}, :c #{:e :f}, :d nil, :e #{:f}, :f nil})
```

Then a no-frills (no cycle check) topological sort

```
(defn tsort [m] 
  (let [depth (fn depth [x] 
                (if (empty? (m x)) 
                  0 
                  (->> x m (map depth) (apply max) inc)))]
    (map val (sort-by key (group-by depth (keys m))))))
```

With output as desired

```
(tsort direct-dependencies)
;=> ([:f :d] [:e] [:c] [:b] [:a])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the clojure graph library [Loom](https://github.com/aysylu/loom).

```
(require '[loom.graph :as g]
         '[loom.alg :as ga]
         '[loom.io :refer [view])

(def dependencies
  (g/digraph {:a #{:b :c}, :b #{:c :e}, :c #{:e :f}, :d nil, :e #{:f}, :f nil}))

(reverse (ga/topsort dependencies))
=> (:f :e :c :b :a :d)

(view dependencies)
```

[image: graph visualisation]

It seems your graph has two roots, :a and :d, so they both can be compiled last.

Loom has some other options that might come in handy, like cycle detection and spanning trees to handle cycles.